# Google cloud function build error with Python 3.7 and firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, python-3.7

Build failed: {"cacheStats": [{"status": "MISS", "hash": "3343848e2474c96b142a614f0fd7e05645326e2100b1e359bbdc5ad7f58543bd", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "global"}, {"status": "MISS", "hash": "3343848e2474c96b142a614f0fd7e05645326e2100b1e359bbdc5ad7f58543bd", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "project"}]}

I keep getting this error and am not able to deploy my function even once. I am working with Python 3.7 and Firebase. Is there something wrong with the code or some platform issue? Offline my code is working fine but I cannot seem to deploy it to google cloud functions.

Comment: Can you try to deploy the hello world function? and share the results also you can try Python 3.8 runtime

Comment: Yes i deployed the hello world and it deployed successfully. I tried python 3.8 too but the same error came up.

Comment: can you share your requirements.txt file and a sample python code ? this is in order to see if some line of code is interfering, please add the code in your question.